# Redirect User to their corresponding View and Templates in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 different user types at the moment.
After a successful login, I want the user to be redirected to its specific dashboard.

Depending on the user, it is possible to load in a different template in a generic view Class:

```
if request.user.user_type == 1:
    # load template A
if request.user.user_type == 2:
    # load template B
```

But I want to have two separate View Classes for each Type.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override get_template_names in a Class Based View that inherits the TemplateResponseMixin

```
   def get_template_names(self):
        if request.user.user_type == 1:
            return ['template1.html']
        else:
            return ['template2.html']
```

Note that the function is expected to return a list, not just the name of a template. Above it is just returning a single item list.

Answer (score 0):

Create Two views for both templates and URLs than simply redirect:

```
if request.user.user_type == 1:
   return redirect("TemplateA")
if request.user.user_type == 2:
   return redirect("TemplateB")
```